# How to access all the iCloud drive files (outside app container) without UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cloud, icloud, cloudkit

I need to make an app that fetches data from `iCloud Drive` (outside app container, all the user files stored in the iCloud) and shows it in `UICollectionView`. Is it possible **without** `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using the iCloud integration. with iCloud integration you can upload and get the data from iCloud here are some reference tutorial to kickstart.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1000-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started
https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/03/icloud-integration-in-swift-30.html

Comment: But you can get just the data that you app stored, isn't it? Can you show to the user files, that he saved into iCloud store outside the app?